# Привязать к последнему уровню иерархии

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Надо вот в этом запросе присоединить товары, но так, чтобы они джойнились по последнему уровню иерархии.

```
SELECT 
 k.Kls_unicode
,k.Kls_Name AS '1'
,ka2.Kls_Name AS '2'
,ka3.Kls_Name AS '3'
,ka4.Kls_Name AS '4'
,ka5.kls_name AS '5'
,ka6.Kls_Name AS '6'
,CASE 
    WHEN k.Kls_Level = 0 AND k.Kls_Parent = 0 THEN k.kls_name
    WHEN k.Kls_UniCode = ka2.Kls_Parent THEN ka2.Kls_Name 
    WHEN ka2.Kls_Parent = ka3.Kls_UniCode THEN ka3.Kls_Name
    WHEN ka3.Kls_Parent = ka4.Kls_UniCode THEN ka4.Kls_Name
    WHEN ka4.Kls_Parent = ka5.Kls_UniCode THEN ka5.Kls_Name
    WHEN ka5.Kls_Parent = ka6.Kls_UniCode THEN ka6.Kls_Name
END 
FROM Kls_All AS k
LEFT JOIN Kls_All AS ka2 ON ka2.kls_parent = k.Kls_UniCode
LEFT JOIN Kls_All AS ka3 ON ka3.kls_parent = ka2.Kls_UniCode
LEFT JOIN Kls_All AS ka4 ON ka4.kls_parent = ka3.Kls_UniCode
LEFT JOIN Kls_All AS ka5 ON ka5.kls_parent = ka4 .Kls_UniCode
LEFT JOIN Kls_All AS ka6 ON ka6.kls_parent = ka5.Kls_UniCode
LEFT JOIN KlsCmpLnk AS kcl ON kcl.Kls_UniCode = k.Kls_UniCode
WHERE k.Kls_Level = 0 AND k.Kls_Parent = 0
  AND k.Kls_Name LIKE '%область применения%'
ORDER BY k.Kls_Name
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так и присоединяйте товары к последней таблице в ваших left join. Как то большего и не скажешь, вы же даже не объяснили что такое "товары" которые надо присоединять. А вообще запрос стоит переписать с использованием рекурсивного CTE что бы не плодить кучу left join.

Comment: Необходимо привязать товары по группам, например, по первой строке : Средства для снижения веса и к ней все товары, а во второй строке уже надо к 3 группе привязывать и т.д.

Comment: А как вы "все товары" собираетесь показать в одной строке ? Количество строк разумеется размножится при привязке ... И да, если вы перепишите запрос на рекурсивный CTE  то любые привязки будут идти к текущему уровню вложенности, т.е. вы получите как раз то что хотите

Comment: По-моему, длинный `CASE` легко заменяется на `COALESCE(ka6.Kls_Name, ka5.Kls_Name, ka4.Kls_Name, ka3.Kls_Name, ka2.Kls_Name, ka.Kls_Name,)`, не? тем более что "по последнему"...

Comment: хотя может я вас не так понял и текущий уровень вам как раз не нужен ... в любом случае покажите структуру таблиц и как они должны клеится (по какому полю) как так выходит что вам приходится заботится что бы товары привязались к нужному уровню иерархии, ведь по идее в товарах должен быть id какой то конкретной ветки и именно к ней они и привяжутся ...